# Using chrome app (postman) in android phone

Tags: android, google-chrome-app, postman

It is possible to use existing chrome application like POSTMAN in android phone? If yes, how to use it? thanks

Answer (score 8):

I assume you are looking for a mobile REST API client. You can have 
apps with similar functionality [Android here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sn.restandroid&hl=en) and [iOS here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/restler/id636518941?mt=8)

Comment: REST Api Client Android has a feature that imports collections from Postmaan

Answer (score 0):

Postman has no Android or IOS app. You can see the postman version on this site. It's just work on Mac, Windows and Linux.

[PostMan official website](https://www.getpostman.com/)